# Drop down of site pages for admin to choose

Tags: 7, views, nodes, routes, navigation

I have a content type which has a link (text type), and admin can manually insert his link. My site pages consist of the pages that work with views module (views page), and also pages that are rendered from `node--mynodename.tpl.php`.

Can I create this select box for site pages for admin to select?

consider I have these pages in my site :
1) homepage  2) contact page  3) about page  4)services page

so I have 4 page ! right ?
so If I need to have a button in my home page for example which I want to link that to contact page ??
in admin should I manually fill the link like: http://www.blabla.com/contact ??
or in drupal and it's modules I have an option to select in my site pages for button link??

Comment: The question is not quite clear; I suggest explaining it a bit more and including an example. That'll help others understand it better.

Comment: ok ! thanks ! I'll edit my question and add some details !